# Which version of Ubuntu to install?

Tags: system-installation

I have an old Toshiba [f10-100](http://www.toshiba.eu/discontinued-products/qosmio-f10-101/)
Specs are:

```
processor: 1.70 GHz Intel® Pentium® M processor 735
hard disk: 60 GB
system memory: 512 MB (although I am in the process of buying an extra 1G ram for it)
graphics: nvidia GeForce Go 6600, 128MB
```

My laptop still runs on XP 32bit and is used mostly for working on my PhD - lots of typing, bit of browsing, lots of article reading (PDFs) and listening to music. I have a netbook for more everyday tasks. The laptop still works very well, if slowly, but needs a new operating system, I suspect I should install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but would appreciate any advice on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current setup i would recommend you install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) after you upgrade the RAM to 1GiB you can go for Ubuntu 13.10 with gnome 3 gnome-session-fallback (no effects), it should run ok.

I hope this is helpful, good luck and welcome to the community.